# Computer freezes after sudo apt upgrade in ubuntu server

Tags: apt, server, upgrade, 22.04

My 13-15 year old Toshiba laptop has issues running ubuntu server 22.04.1. When I run 'sudo apt upgrade' or 'sudo apt dist-upgrade' it results in the following repeated over and over almost instantly. "Uhhuh. NMI received for for unknown reason 2d on cpu 0. Do you have a strange power saving mode enabled? Dazed and confused, but trying to continue" and I eventually have to force reboot. The pc specs are: AMD E-450 APU with Radeon HD Graphics (dual core @ 1650MHz), 4GB of ram, and the bios is InsydeH2O version 1.8 rev 3.5. I have searched around and everyone keeps pointing to the NVidia drivers. After accidentally leaving it on without logging in it produced the same result after a while.

Comment: This can often be resolved by disabling "c-states" in the BIOS/UEFI. The issue happens when the processor is unable to cycle to the expected bus rate in time. Note that doing this will result in the processor consuming a bit more power during idle time so, if you regularly operate on battery power, you may need to stay closer to an outlet.

Comment: @matigo cant find the option in the bios and “intel_idle.max_cstate=0” doesnt seemed to have done anything

Comment: One would expect that `intel_idle.max_cstate` would only work on Intel processors. If your BIOS/UEFI does not support the option to control the c-state, then I'm not sure what to suggest. There are documented `nmi_` codes that can be set in GRUB, but none of them seem to be effective over the long term in resolving this issue. You may have stumbled across a bug that will need to be [reported to Canonical (via LaunchPad)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug/?no-redirect) so that they can investigate the matter 

Comment: @matigo do you know what source package is causing the problem so I can better report the bug?

Comment: Unfortunately I do no have that information. To the best of my knowledge it's within the kernel itself. I do not have a system with your CPU, so I cannot contribute to the investigation. Apologies 